# How to double elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with a shape similar to `(3114, 7, 36, 64, 1)`. This example is a batch of 3114 sets of 7 images, each image 36 by 64 grayscale pixels. This is for a 3d Convolutional Neural Network, but what I want to do is double the batch size for more data for my model. Basically, I want to take these 3114 sets of 7 and duplicate each one to create a batch of size 6228. I know this is a pretty basic question, but I am not too familiar with numpy arrays. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicating all your values is not the same as augmenting your dataset... You're only learning the same relationships twice. Also, your batchsize dimension should not be the first, otherwise your memory access will be very inefficient.

Comment: So my model won't be any better if I have 10 images than 20 images if half of the 20 images are repeats exactly? The only reason I ask this is that I can't augment my images because they are sports images, I don't want my model being fed bad form or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either numpy's .repeat() or .concatenate() functions